Mapping between the serial port number and slot number in SIM Bank(Box)
I need to map the serial port number and slot of sim bank.
My sim bank has 256 slots (8 port, 32 slot ) and connected 8 serial port in every port of box.
How can I get the port number of bank mapped with 8 COM ports?
import serial.tools.list_ports
import logging
import time

def execute_command(modem, command, wait_time=2):
    try:
        modem.write(f"{command}\r".encode())
        time.sleep(wait_time)
        return modem.readlines()
    except serial.SerialException as e: 
        print(f"Error executing command {command} in {modem.port}: {str(e)}")
        return []

try:
    modem = serial.Serial("COM" + str(real_port), 115200, timeout=1)
    for i in range(132, 164):
        sub_modem.append(serial.Serial("COM" + str(i), 115200, timeout=1))

    print(f"########## Real Port: {real_port} ##########")

    for index, modem_cop in enumerate(sub_modem):
        for port in range(1, 9):
            formatted_string = "AT+SWIT{:02d}-{:04d}".format(port, 1)
            response = execute_command(modem, formatted_string)

            try:
                operator = ''.join([line.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore') for line in response])
            except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
                print(f"Decoding error: {e}")
                continue
                
            if str("SWITCH OK") in operator:
                try:
                    res_cop = execute_command(modem_cop, "AT+COPS=?")
                    try:
                        oper_cop = ''.join([line.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore').strip() for line in res_cop])
                  
                    except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
                        print(f"Decoding error: {e}")
                        continue

               
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)

    for index in enumerate(sub_modem):
        sub_modem[index].close()
    modem.close()

    print(f"########## Real Port: {real_port} ##########")
    logging.info(f"########## Real Port: {real_port} ##########")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")


You could write a Python script using the pyserial library to query each COM port and send specific commands that identify the corresponding port and slots on the SIM bank.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
